# Excel Macro - VBA: Selection or range is not accepted as a passed parameter to another function. Runtime error 424 encountered

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple `Sub()` to pass the current selected cell/s as range to another function but I'm getting an Error 424: Object required when I run the `sub`.

I already checked SO and saw other Error 424 posts but all are of a different case than mine.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub ShowRemoveLicTypModal()
    Dim MsgBoxInput As Integer

    'Show confirmation for removing license types
    MsgBoxInput = MsgBox("Would you like to remove the selected license types?", _
    vbYesNo)

    Select Case MsgBoxInput
        Case vbYes
            RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Selection) '==Error 424 encountered on this line
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        Case vbNo
    End Select
End Sub
```

The line `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Selection)` where I'm getting the error. It calls the function below. I've already removed all the code from this function for debugging but I'm still getting the error.

```
Private Function RemoveLicenseTypeFromList(InputRange As Range)
'Nothing here
End Function
```

I've already tried the following:

Assign selection to a Range variable

```
Public Sub ShowRemoveLicTypModal()
    Dim MsgBoxInput As Integer
    Dim Temp As Range

    Set Temp = Selection

    'Show confirmation for removing license types
    MsgBoxInput = MsgBox("Would you like to remove the selected license types?", _
    vbYesNo)

    Select Case MsgBoxInput
        Case vbYes
            RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Temp)
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        Case vbNo
    End Select
End Sub
```

Watch the `Selection` / `Range` being passed to `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList` and I can see that the type is `Object/Range` OR (`Range/Range`) for `Temp` so the types should be matching.

[image]

**Questions:**
What could possibly be causing this error and how do I fix it?

**My selection:**
Cell A13 shown highlighted on the image. I also tried changing selection all with similar results.
[image]

Comment: you only need the brackets when returning to an object. `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList  temp`

Comment: If an error persists after removing all code from the called sub or function the error must be in the call itself. I think with that logic you would have found the error yourself because when you type `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList(Selection)` VBA will insert a space before the bracket, indicating that it isn't required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets!!

```
RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Selection)
```

should be

```
RemoveLicenseTypeFromList Selection
```

because you are not assigning the return value from `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList` to a variable.

---

And it is a bit pointless to have a `Function` that doesn't return a value.  (It returns a `Variant/Empty` by default, but it's a bit pointless **always** returning a `Variant/Empty`)  Your `Function` should be a `Sub` if it isn't going to return anything.

Comment: Or use `Call RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Selection)`

Comment: @FunThomas - `Call` is obsolete syntax.

Comment: Holy crud. It's that simple I am dumbfounded. Thank you kind sir! I tried both ways and it worked.

Comment: Based on the function name `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList`, it sounds like although you currently have an empty function, it probably won't stay that way and might be modifying data so would be better as a Sub anyway.

Comment: Snaps to the 2nd note. I have been working with macros for a while but I never knew this difference. This is noted and will adjust accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Function should return a value and the vbe is expecting a variable to receive the function `RemoveLicenseFromList` will return.

You can either remove the braces here `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Temp)` to make it like `RemoveLicenseTypeFromList Temp`
or call your function as `Call RemoveLicenseTypeFromList (Temp)`.

This applies to `Sub`'s too.